# How to connect a database to a project in OpenServer?

Tags: mysql, phpstorm

I have a project for my thesis, and there is a database that I need to somehow connect to it. How to do it?

info: the database was made in MySQL. I have MySQL, PhpStorm installed. The site itself was written in PHP.

Tried only to connect MySQL to OpenServer. It didn’t work, I didn’t go anywhere else.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. Do you want to be able to see DB structure / make queries / edit records that you have in your existing MySQL database and do it from PhpStorm? Or you want your PHP code to be able to communicate to your MySQL database?

Comment: BTW -- "openserver" -- do you mean this Open Server Panel one? https://ospanel.io/

Comment: For accessing MySQL database in PhpStorm -- check the following official help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/mysql.html You would need: 1) the address of the server (if it's local then `127.0.0.1` should do); 2) Username and password of the DB user; 3) existing database name to connect to; 4) MySQL driver for the Database tools (the IDE can download it for you when creating a data source)